# Make light-grey text darker on Mac (white background)

Tags: macos, text, color

I have a MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra with a white desktop background.

My problem is that any light-grey text (e.g. the words "Answers for your Apple questions" under the Ask Different logo at top left) is so light I cannot read it.

What can I do to make any light-grey text a darker color?

Comment: If only a few web pages a way is to use stylus https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/wiki or similar to change the web site. I

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, the first thing I'd do is change your accessibility display settings. More specifically:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences
2. Click on the Accessibility preference pane
3. Within the left-hand pane click the Display icon (it's usually the 4th one down)
4. Now to the right you'll see a number of checkboxes and sliders relating to accessibility display settings
5. Have a play with these to see if they improve the readability of light-grey text

Comment: It didn't help on macOS High Sierra. For example on safari tab menu, its impossible to read tabs with dark background that has gray font color @Monomeeth♦